# Is there any way of automating a Journey to pause?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation

I would like to know if there is any possibility to automate a Journey to pause without manual interaction in Journey Builder. Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this via API in Automation Studio or on a CloudPage/Code Resource.

> Pause your running journeys in Marketing Cloud Journey Builder for up
> to 14 days using the new Journey Pause API, and when ready, use the
> API to resume the paused journey.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_may_2020_dev_journey_pause.htm&language=en_US&type=5